# How do I install the "sparse_dot_topn" Package in Anaconda Installer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I am trying to install the "sparse_dot_topn" package in Alibaba Cloud ECS instance. Firstly I tried to install it through the Anaconda installer.

> conda install sparse_dot_topn

It throws like there is no package available

So I tried to install via pip

> Pip install spare_dot_topn

But it throws me the following error

[image: Error]

What am I missing? Please leave your suggestions

Comment: If I am able to resolve it then why I am going to ask it in stack overflow, I too had no idea by seeing the error. This is the error I got, I don't know what else you are expecting me to give... before just downvoting please consider it twice... @phd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sparse_dot_topn` requires Cython, try installing it this way:

```
pip install cython
pip install git+https://github.com/ing-bank/sparse_dot_topn.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it first with pip install and failed. Then I tried within Anaconda terminal with the following comment and it was succesfull.

```
conda install -c conda-forge sparse_dot_topn
```